# $x^2+y^2+z^2=3125$ , where $x$ is a real number and $y$ and $z$ are natural numbers. If $50\le y\le 52$, number of solutions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$y$ can have minimum value of $50$. Therefore, $x^2+z^2=625.$

$y$ can have value of $51$. In that case $x^2+z^2=524.$

$y$ can have maximum value of $52$ , where $x^2+z^2=421.$

In first case, when $x=0$ , $ z=25$ . $x=15$ , $z=20$ .

After this it is difficult to go further. Please explain how to go ahead with the solution.

Comment: Is $y$  real or whole number?

Comment: But both $y=20$ and $y=25$ contradict $50\le y\le 52$?

Comment: To expand upon @labbhattacharjee query - You state in the heading that $y$ is a real number but then only consider whole number values of $y$ in the question. Please clarify your intention or no one will be able to answer clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Instead of writing z, I wrote y. Edited it.

Comment: @MinhazPathan: Kindly change the first part of your question to _"$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 3125$, where $x,y,z$ are **integers**..."_ If you allow that $y,z$ are just reals, then there are infinitely many solutions and the problem has no appeal.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, edited.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$50\le y\le52\implies50^2\le y^2\le52^2$$

$$3125-52^2\le x^2+z^2\le3125-50^2$$

As $z$ is real, $z^2\ge0$  How  many integer$(n)$s exist such that $$3125-52^2\le n^2\le3125-50^2$$

Comment: So if x = 21 we get y^2 + z^2 =2684. So y >= 50 and x^2 <= 184. How do we classify the solutions and to answer "how many solutions" isn't the answer infinite?  (If the questing is how many values ox x solve it, then it is fine.  But I think the question as stated is flawed)

Comment: @fleablood, So, $$20<\sqrt{3125-52^2}\le n\le\sqrt{3125-52^2}=25$$ or $$-21\ge n\ge-25$$ So $n$ can have only $2\cdot5$ values